# What happens in mysql if the database is updated during a lengthy select?

Tags: sql, report, mysql-5.5, totara

So I have a fairly lengthy Select Statement (~5200 seconds), used for generating a report.

It accesses a dozen or so tables etc. ...

What happens when anything is written to the server on any of these tables, during my select statement?

Comment: depend by your locking level   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Comment: And how does it behave when no locking level is set?

Comment: a defualt locking level is always set  .. so check for you default level

Comment: Hmm sorry I tried to google it, but I dont quite understand. Where can I see what my default level locking is?

Comment: try searching  the default isolation level for your db engine (eg: INNODB)